# After re-compressing data, the result differs from the uncompressed source. How do I reproduce the same data again?

Tags: c#, compression

I am given an byte array of compressed data, which takes up 27878 bytes. It starts with

```
78-9C-ED-BD-09
```

so it should be readable with DeflateStream, which it is. The uncompressed data is a XML file. I want to modify some values in this XML and then compress it again, to save it back to its source.

But even without any modifications, just decompressing and compressing again the result differs from the source, which causes the target-applications, which reads this byte array to crash.

For compression and uncompression I used these methods found in Stackoverflow

```
private static MemoryStream Decompress(byte[] input)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();

    using (var compressStream = new MemoryStream(input))
    using (var decompressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        decompressor.CopyTo(output);

    output.Position = 0;
    return output;
}
```

```
public byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
{


    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    DeflateStream compressionStream =
        new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress);
    compressionStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);

    compressionStream.Close();

    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

---

**Edit 04/23/19**

As it was pointed out be a comment, that has been deleted, the deflate methods are not suited to compress data. Instead, with the DotNetZip library and some work in this library it was possible to create the same data again!